# error in dimension for adder in negative feedback loop

Tags: control-system, matlab, simulink, state-space, steady-state

im a universiity student i was trying to model this state space with simulink i tried to use the state block but got the same error i think i need to use mux i already checked the dimensions for A B C and Kc can anyone help?[image: this is the error]

[image: this is the simulink design]

[image: this is the code for matlab where it shows the values of A B C and Kc]

Comment: System is SISO system. B matrix has only one column. So single input. So Kc should be a single number. What is the actual value of Kc, is it a 3 element matrix? It should not be

Comment: i tried it with only one integer and it worked thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

B matrix has only one column. So single input. The figure indicates that gain block Kc tries to have 3 outputs which cannot fit into the input of the system. The gain in the gain block needs to be a scalar.

### Edit

From the Matlab documentation website

> place computes a gain matrix K such that the state feedback u = –**Kx** places the closed-loop poles at the locations p.

The place command is for **state feedback**. But since you have a C matrix with only one row from which you are feeding back, you need to use a technique which uses **output feedback**, not state feedback. This is why Kc turned out to be a 1x3 matrix instead of a scalar. For a SISO system with output feedback, the feedback gain should be a scalar value.